# Clearing a published presence with UCMA 3.0

Tags: c#, lync-2010, ucma

I'm publishing a user presence in a Trusted Application Endpoint, but I also would like to clear this presence when it is no longer needed.

Is the only option to do so to terminate the UserEndpoint instance?

I'm using this code snippet:

```
    user.Endpoint.LocalOwnerPresence.BeginPublishPresence(
        user.categories,
        arBeginPublishPresence =>
        {
            try
            {
                user.Endpoint.PresenceServices.EndUpdatePresenceState(arBeginPublishPresence);
                logger.log("Published presence for {0} with state {1}.", user.SipUserUri, newState.Availability);
            }
            catch (RealTimeException ex)
            {
                logger.log("Failed publishing presence for {0}. {1}", user.SipUserUri, ex);
            }
        },
        null);
```

where user.Endpoint is the UserEndpoint for that user, and user.categories are the list of PresenceCategoryWithMetaData objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - I'm amazed this actually works! you're calling BeginPublishPresence on the LocalOwnerPresence object, and then in the aysnc callback calling EndUpdatePresenceState on the PresenceServices object. Please tell me this is a typo, otherwise i'm going to have to throw out everything I thought I knew about Lync development and async programming ;o)

Anyway - assuming you're publishing presence with

`LocalOwnerPresence.BeginPublishPresence`

(and calling the corresponding EndPublishPresence in the async callback), you can call

`LocalOwnerPresence.BeginDeletePresence`

to delete the publication.

Comment: I got most of this from the book Professional Unified Communications Development with Microsoft Lync Server 2010, Chapter 9, the part about "Publishing Presence with a Presence Grammar". If this is dead wrong,

Comment: I tried to use BeginDeletePresence, but outside the async callback code of the original BeginPublishPresence. I'm used to Java, c# is still a bit confusing.

Comment: As I stated elsewhere, I had a bug where I used a new instance Id for each presence update. Not only did it man BeginDeletePresence would never work unless I kept track of them all, and at some point Lync gets fed up and terminates the session.